# Fetch only one record from first order by and rest from second order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT s.*
     , g.* 
  from tbl_section1 as s
     , tbl_game as g 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_game_visit_count AS gvc 
    ON g.game_id = gvc.game_id 
 where s.category_id = g.game_id 
 ORDER 
    BY g.udate DESC
     , gvc.visit_count DESC
```

which works fine.

But I want to fetch the first record ordered by `g.udate`, and then the rest of the records ordered by `gvc.visit_count`.

Is this possible using mysql query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible by using `UNION`(*not `UNION ALL`, since we don't want to duplicate rows* ) between two queries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses inside parentheses

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM
  (
    SELECT s.*, g.* 
      FROM tbl_section1 as s
     INNER JOIN tbl_game as g ON s.category_id = g.game_id 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_game_visit_count AS gvc ON g.game_id = gvc.game_id 
     ORDER BY g.udate DESC
     LIMIT 1 
   ) q
 UNION
    SELECT s.*, g.* 
      FROM tbl_section1 as s
     INNER JOIN tbl_game as g ON s.category_id = g.game_id 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_game_visit_count AS gvc ON g.game_id = gvc.game_id 
     ORDER BY gvc.visit_count DESC;
```

*P.S. Because of your original query I kept `DESC` options for `ORDER BY`, you can get rid of them if you want regular ascending ordering.*

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, I got an idea from your query and modified  little bit and it works fine. :)